# Call Async/await function from non async and add value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm new in async function. I'm trying to apply it for UrlFetchApp.fetch.When there is a network problem, it throws an undefined error because there is no response code available. Therefore I gave a try to async function.

```
var addStamp = obj => {
  obj.date = new Date();
  return obj;
}
var decideWho = (form) => {
  var choice = form.choice;
  var obj = { key1 : 'func1(form.input1)',
key2 : 'func2(form.input2)'......};
return addStamp(eval(obj[choice]||obj[default]));
}

const fetchUrl = async (url, params) => {
  let data = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params).getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(data);
}

var func1 = async (val) => {
  var params = {...};
  let response = await fetchUrl(val, params);
  return response["message"];
}

var func2 = async (val) => {
  var params = {...};
  let response = await UrlFetch.app(val, params);
  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
       var result = {step:"file", result:response};
    } else var result = {step: null, result: ""};
  return result;
}
```

when func1 is called through decideWho, it returns result and addStamp is performed so date is added to the return value.

But when func2 is called, it returns value correctly but from decideWho, addStamp is not performed before it return so 'date' is undefined. In this incident, I have to call addStamp within the func2 while returning the value.

**How to avoid this undefined?**

I'm sure I'm messing up with async/await.

I tried to put async/await in decideWho by declaring extra value with await then wrap it with addStamp then return it.

```
let result = await eval(obj[choice]||obj[default]);
return addStamp(result);
}
```

However when decideWho is called from clientside with google.script.run, it throws undefined error. I guess somewhere I need to add await one more time but I can't find out where.

*Couple of points worth to mention*
(*Because the form from client side calls various function, I decided to put bunch into one bucket. i.e. regardless of the option, it will call only decideWho of server function from the client, and through option's value, it will choose which function will be called with parameters. And each function returns value and addStamp from decideWho so that I don't have to repeat this process/code in each and every function.
**Only func1 and func2 are async but not others.)

**This worked**

```
const addStamp = async (obj) => {
  const temp = await obj;
  temp.date = new Date();
  return temp;
}
```

Or shorter version

```
const addStamp = async (obj) => (
  { ...(await obj),
  date: new Date()})
```

Thanks to Josh and Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you. It has several other refactors in it too...

The basic issue looks to me that you are not awaiting your async functions when you add them to the object.

```
// use const - variables are unreliable!
// Rest Spread syntax
const addStamp = obj => ({
  ...obj,
  date: new Date();
})

// this can throw on a network or JSON parse error,
// the fn that calls (and awaits / .then chains)
// on decideWho needs to handle that.
const decideWho = async form => {
  const { choice } = form;
  // you need to await these, they are async
  const obj = { 
     key1 : await func1(form.input1),
     key2 : await func2(form.input2)
  };
  return addStamp(eval(obj[choice]||obj[default]));
}

// can throw from network or JSON parse
const fetchUrl = async (url, params) => {
  let data = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params).getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(data);
}

const func1 = async val => {
  const params = {...};
  let response = await fetchUrl(val, params);
  return response["message"];
}

const func2 = async val => {
  const params = {...};
  const response = await UrlFetch.app(val, params);
  // use a ternary, and no intermediate var
  return (response.getResponseCode() === 200) ?
     {step:"file", result:response} :
     {step: null, result: ""};
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey so I was writing something super similar to you (awaiting the functions in an object and mapping them) but you beat me to it. Figured I might as well post my workings/thoughts too: https://codepen.io/AndyMardell/pen/BaNQVzB?editors=0012

Comment: Dude, you were going all in on that one! Nice work. Arrow function single line or returning an object (like on line 10 of your codepen) don't need `{`. To return an object you can do: `() => ({a: 3})`

Comment: Ah sure, I just tend to use explicit returns when trying to teach someone - I think they're a little clearer. Relevant discussion: https://twitter.com/markdalgleish/status/1225205953093459968

Comment: Thanks for both of you. I learned many points apart from my original question. However, for some reason, I can't ditch eval. If I keep the functions without quotation mark, when I call funcMap[choice], it iterates all functions. And by making decideWho async didn't work. As Josh mentioned in first line, main problem was adding an item to the obj. There I added async/await voila! But one thing I was wondering is that, why first func1 always works and func2 never worked in the first place. Then a thought came maybe JSON.parse made it sync but func2 doesn't have that. Thanks for helping me!!!

Comment: If you want to get to the bottom of that eval thing, make a minimal reproducer and open another question. I would be very concerned if I were writing code, and I didn't understand what was going on. If that's what you know that you don't know about how your code operates, what you don't know that you don't know could cause other bugs that are hard to trace, and more work for you in the future.

Comment: @Josh Wulf Alright. I'll open another question for that. Thanks for the guideline.